# how to take formatted input in c++?

Tags: c++, cin

Well i know how to do this in c, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    scanf("%d:%d,%d",&a,&b,&c);
    printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);

    return 0;
}
```

But for to do this in c++? Can `cin` be use like scanf?

Comment: you can use the same syntax I believe, but you have to include the same header as well

Comment: why do you need specify %d, `cin` did it for you implicitly

Comment: You can use `cin` to get specific types e.g. int etc. You could get the int then then colon then the comma then the number in steps. You could write your own operator >> for a struct though, but would have to do that in steps.

Comment: Well you could read the input as one line, and then check if it matches a regular expression (example : https://regex101.com/r/8YMxEP/1), and if it does not match ask for input again. This you can do with std::regex_match from [<regex>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since input format is `"%H:%M,%s"` I suspect that a time is an input.
In such case there is better simpler way to do it:

```cpp
    std::tm t{};
    while(std::cin >> std::get_time(&t, "%H:%M,%S")) {
        std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%H %M %S") << '\n';
    }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Y5o9cYc4G

Comment: Yes, it was mean to store time. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

regular expression example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    bool input_ok{ false };

    std::regex rx{ "(\\d+):(\\d+).(\\d+)" }; // regex of groups
    std::smatch match;
    std::string input;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter value (format d:d.d, where d can be one ore more number ) : ";
        std::cin >> input;
    }
    while (!std::regex_match(input, match, rx));

    // match[0] will contain full match
    // match[1] will contain first digits, match[2] second group of digits

    std::cout << "first group of digits  : " << std::stoi(match[1]) << "\n";
    std::cout << "second group of digits : " << std::stoi(match[2]) << "\n";
    std::cout << "third group of digits : " << std::stoi(match[3]) << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution:**

You can use multiple `>>` operations, and store every separator as `char` or `std::string`.

For example:

```cpp
int minutes, seconds, milliseconds;
char tmp1, tmp2;
cin >> minutes >> tmp1 >> seconds >> tmp2 >> milliseconds;
if (tmp1 != ':' || tmp2 != '.')
    cout << "Error in the input!";
else
    cout << minutes << ' ' << seconds << ' ' << milliseconds;
```

**Complex solution:**

Use `std::regex`, which is written in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73972197/12852914).

Answer (score -2):

```
int a,b,c;
cin>>a>>b>>c;

string resultString = "s1:s2.s3";
resultString=resultString.replace(s1,a);
resultString=resultString.replace(s2,b);
resultString=resultString.replace(s3,c);
cout<<resultString;
return 0;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: This answer is erroneous and misleading, as `replace`  does not have a required overload, and `s1`,...,`s3` have not been defined.